# When can you switch the order of differentiation and integration?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Suppose I have some functions $f(t), g(f)$ and some constants $a, b$ and I'm computing the integral

$$\int_{a}^{b} \left(\frac{d}{dt}g(f(t))\right) df$$

Then would it be valid to compute:

$$\left[\frac{d}{dt}\int g(f(t)) df\right]_{a}^{b}$$

If it's not always valid, then when is this appropriate? Or is it just invalid?

[EDIT] In the specific example I'm working on, $g(f) = \log(f)$ and $f(t) = \sin(t)^{2\sqrt{t}}$

And the integral is $$\int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{f(t)}\frac{df}{dt} df$$

[EDIT 2] To provide some more context, I arrived at this integral by going a substitution. The original integral was

$$\int_{0.5}^{1} \left(\frac{d}{dt} sin(t)^{\sqrt{t}}\right)^2 dt$$

To simplify the algebra I replaced $\log(\sin(t))\sqrt{t}$ with $h(t)$ and got:

$$\int_{0.5}^{1} h'(t)^{2}e^{2h(t)} dt$$

Then using $f(t) = \sin(t)^{2\sqrt{t}} = e^{2h(t)}$ I got $df = 2h'(t)e^{2h(t)}dt$ and rewrote the integral as

$$\frac{1}{4}\int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{f(t)}\frac{df}{dt} df$$ where are $a$ and $b$ are new limits

Comment: Your notation seems a bit deficient to me, can you give a more precise example to show what you're talking about? Also just for switching integration and differentiation in general I suggest you check out the Leibniz rule for integration

Comment: @StephenDonovan I've added in the specifics of the integral that I'm looking at right now.

Comment: The last $df$ is meant to be a $dt$ yeah? If so then you should just be able to do this with a substitution, $u = f(t)$ and rewrite the integral as $\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} \frac1{u} du$

Comment: @StephenDonovan No the last $df$ should be a $df$

Comment: @StephenDonovan Sorry I realised I made a mistake in the orginal definition of $f(t)$ and I've also added some more context to how I got to this final integral from the original question.

Answer (score 1):

The notation is confusing we slightly, are the limits stated $f\in[a,b]$ or $t$?. Also as @Stephen said look up the Leibniz (Leeb-nuhz) rule for integration, which states the interchangeability of integral and differential operator, which if the limits are constant amounts to:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^bf(x,t)\,dx=\int_a^b\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x,t)\,dx$$

If $a,b$ are dependent on $t$ it becomes much more complicated:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)\,dt=f(x,b(x))\frac{db(x)}{dx}-f(x,a(x))\frac{da(x)}{dx}+\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,t)\,dt$$

Note that in the above expression we are differentiating wrt $x$

Comment: The limits stated are $ f \in [a ,b]$ and not $t$.

Comment: Is that the proper pronunciation for Leibniz? I've been saying "Libe-nitz" this whole time

Comment: In general the rule for German names is the second letter is pronounced, thus i agree with Stephen. That weird parenthetical really threw me.

Comment: @dbx honestly not sure, google gives different pronunciations for America and the UK, so I just went for the UK one, It could be incorrect though

Comment: @StephenDonovan just commented above to show where I got it from, I think we need a native german speaker to clarify this haha